# [rosrun] Count' find executable named ...?

Tags: rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey all,

I am trying to move my catkin workspace from my old computer to my new one. I copied the folder from my old computer, pasted into the new one with ROS installed. catkin)make gave no errors. However, when i try to run my program,  i get this error:

$ rosrun sim_pkg sim_init
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named sim_init below /home/icepaka89/algsim_ws/src/sim_pkg

Clearly there is a problem with ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. But I can't seem to figure it out? Does anyone know an easy way to fix this? I made sure i ran source devel/setup.bash before running my program. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243017/%5Brosrun%5D-count%27-find-executable-named-...-?/) by [icepaka89](https://answers.ros.org/users/26952/icepaka89/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2016-09-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to go to the directory where your executable is, and check if it is there. Usually, the executable generated is in the `[WORKSPACE_DIR]/devel/lib/[PKG_NAME]/`.

If the executable is not generated, then something wrong with catkin_make or your source code.

If the executable is generated, then something wrong with you environment variables.

---

Originally posted by [Shay](https://answers.ros.org/users/27777/shay/) with karma: 763 on 2016-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1